# MapR sandbox work instructions

Tags: mapr

After I installed MapR sandbox in my laptop, how to practice the sample exercises on MapR sandbox? Where I can find the instructions?
Thank You.
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Once you have started the VM you can connect to the VM using ssh and do all most of the work from the session.

If you have not changed anything to the configuration, the Sandbox is accessible usin glocal ssh connection (NAT) on the port 2222, so connect to it as follow:

Virtual box
    ssh mapr@localhost -p 2222

You should have all the instructions about the sandbox, running on:

- [Virtual Box](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/51/#SandboxHadoop/t_install_sandbox_vbox.html)
- [VMWare](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/51/#SandboxHadoop/t_install_sandbox_vmware.html)

I do not know which exercices you want to do, you can find all the tutorials here:

https://www.mapr.com/products/mapr-sandbox-hadoop/tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set up the mapr sandbox on your Laptop, you should check if the node is working properly using

```
maprcli node list
```

Look for healthy and check the services running.

After that you should try to work with your Map Reduce program.

A book by "OReilly.Hadoop.The.Definitive.Guide" is a good way to start learning with hadoop, mapr and other ecosystems provided under this distributed system. 
There are other tutorials also available on the net that you can choose.